# How do I report spam/scam attempts in Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have kept the conversation open so this guy can be traced.  He is using the persona of a topnotch COO of a very large reputable company in USA to "hire" people, hooking them via Freelancer.com.

I can't find where to report abuse on Hangouts.

I know how to block him but want him caught and his mails investigated as he is using this to extort money and personal details from people.

Comment: This question has been bumped by a Community user 18 times.

Comment: I’m voting to close as Google retired the Hangouts web application at the end of 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following link and select Google+ in the list of applications and provide all the information to the team so that they can investigate his profile.

https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905#ts=1115658

The above link is to be used is someone is doing something illegal, assuming the identity of someone they are not etc. In order to make complains here, you must submit the feedback for each service separately(like one for gmail, another one for Hangouts etc). This feedback then goes to the Google support team which may ask you for evidence to back your claim and once everything is in order they will take the appropriate action from their end.

Comment: This answer is obsolete as Google+ was retired. Also, it's not shown on the linked webpage.