# How do I report a scam on Hangouts?

Tags: google-workspace, security, google-hangouts, google-feedback

A so-called Army orthopedic physician scammed me out of a large sum of money on Hangouts.  His original email was usarmydavid1234@gmail.com. He said he needed help sending his consignment box from Aleppo, Syria, to the US.

Comment: Related (see the titles on the linked section of the side panel) https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113539/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130027/88163

Answer (score 1):

On https://hangouts.google.com or https://gmail.com

1. Double click the contact to report to open the chat window
2. Click the **gear** button
   [image]
3. Click the **Block & report** button
   [image]
4. Check the **Also report** checkbox
   [image]

Older related Q&A (they don't mentions the above steps)

- [How do I report spam/scam attempts in Hangouts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113539/88163)
- [How do I report scammers on Google Hangouts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130027/88163)